# I'm trying to make a slide-in menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've written all my HTML, assigned ID's to the two different panels that will be used as the main body and the slide-in menu. But when I add the jQuery, it doesn't seem to respond. This has worked with the use of Code Academy, but no go with anything else.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div ID="menu">
        <div ID="exit">
            <img src="http://www.thaddius.net/mems/hvit.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li><a ID="Links" href="http://www.thaddius.net/soup.webm/">Suppe, ja?</a></li>
            <li><a ID="Links" href="http://www.thaddius.net/skjermavbildninger">Skjermdump?</a></li>
            <li><a ID="Links" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MC0hV3dea9g">Gotta go fast!</a></li>
            <li><a ID="Links" href="http://www.frankrobert.no">Men, Flørenes?</a></li>
            <li><a ID="Links" href="http://www.mjaavatten.no/">Men, Mjaavatten?</a></li>
            <li><a ID="Links" href="http://www.nittenbokstaverlang.com/">Men, Kristian?</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img src="http://www.thaddius.net/mems/longlast.jpg"
    </div></div>
    <div ID="body">
        <div ID="open">
            <img src="http://www.thaddius.net/mems/hvit.jpg"/>
            MENU
        </div>
    </div>




<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#Links:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 110%;
}
#Links:link{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#Links:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
#menu {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 8px;
    left: -288px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 272px;
}
li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-family: Comic sans MS;
    margin: left;
}
#exit {
    cursor: pointer
}
#open {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;

}
body {
    background-color: black;

}
```

JS:

```
var main = function() {
    $('#open').click(function(){
        $('#menu').animate({left: '0px'}, 400);
        $('body').animate({left: '288px'}, 400);
    });
    $('#exit').click(function(){
        $('#menu').animate({left:'-288px'}, 400);
        $('body').animate({left:'0px'},400);
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Make sure you include jquery library or not?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/h8rhoqnf/1/ Working for me. Make sure you're adding `jQuery` only once on the page

Comment: yeah.. the given code appears to be correct.. there is something related to  jQuery inclusion maybe.. whats the console error you are getting?

Comment: also, id should not be repeated. consider changing id="links" to class="links"

Comment: You should also consider using CSS for this. More elegant and efficient : http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/

Comment: @ArmelLarcier I wouldn't use pure CSS, but It would be a good idea to make the animation and positioning CSS and just use javascript to toggle a class.

Comment: @moss exactly. Let's not get radical ;)

Comment: See answer. not pure css but much cleaner I think.

Answer (score 1):

Alright let's do this.
Start by including the CDN version of jQuery in your `head` tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
```

So first you need to start get compliant and remove these identical IDs on links. You don't even need attributes to target these links with CSS. Replace `#Links` with `#menu li a`. That won"t affect performance; CSS selectors remain pretty fast after all.

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="exit">
        <img src="http://www.thaddius.net/mems/hvit.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.thaddius.net/soup.webm/">Suppe, ja?</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.thaddius.net/skjermavbildninger">Skjermdump?</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MC0hV3dea9g">Gotta go fast!</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.frankrobert.no">Men, Flørenes?</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mjaavatten.no/">Men, Mjaavatten?</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.nittenbokstaverlang.com/">Men, Kristian?</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="http://www.thaddius.net/mems/longlast.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="body">
    <div id="open">
        <img src="http://www.thaddius.net/mems/hvit.jpg" />
        MENU
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 110%;
}
#menu li a:link{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#menu li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
#menu {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 8px;
    left: -288px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 272px;
}
#menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-family: Comic sans MS;
    margin: left;
}
#exit {
    cursor: pointer
}
#open {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}


/* Animate any left property value change */
#body, #menu {
    /* Add vendor prefixes too if you're not pre-compiling your stylesheet */
    -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    /* This is the standard declaration */
    transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
/* Toggle menu open */
body.menu-open #menu{
    left: 0;
}
body.menu-open #body{
    left: 288px;
}
```

**Javascript**
this will toggle the class `menu-open` on the body element when the user clicks on either toggles.

```
$(function(){
    var $toggles = $('#open, #exit'), $body = $('body');
    $toggles.bind('click', function(){ $body.toggleClass('menu-open'); });
});
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8rhoqnf/2/)